# How do you show that the degree of an irreducible polynomial over the reals is either one or two?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

The degree of irreducible polynomials over the reals is either one or two.

Is it possible to prove it without using complex numbers? Or without using fundamental theorem of algebra?

Comment: I removed the tags (calculus) and (real-analysis) because the question itself is algebraic in nature, (which doesn't exclude the possibility of an analytic solution).

Comment: I took the liberty to fix some typos and a bit of grammar ... I like the question BTW!

Comment: The intermediate value theorem solves this problem for odd degree polynomials. I don't even know where to start for even degree polynomials.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible.  The fact that a polynomial with real coefficients and irreducible over the reals stems from the fact that any complex roots must come in conjugate pairs.  I'm not 100% sure about that such a proof is not possible, so I'm not posting it as an answer.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski not meaning to be unkind but that sounds like an argument from lack of imagination... certainly complex numbers have an important role here, but it seems pretty hard to rule out that there might be another perspective on the matter.

Comment: This is why I only stated my comment as an opinion.

Comment: I think it is possible. I have an idea which I don't wish to pursue. Induction. Assume that any polynomial of degree $2n$ has a factor of degree $2$. Take an arbitrary polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $2(n+1)$ and try to find $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ with degrees $2n$ and $2$ respectively such that $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$. It's not necessary to find the coefficients, it suffices to show that a solution to the equations (on the coefficients) exists.

Comment: @GitGud: Exactly what I thought!

Comment: I belive that it is impossible to prove it without real analysis, because otherwise it becomes true over some other things (may be $\mathbb{Q}$, algebraic numbers?). That's why i added tags calculus and real analysis

Comment: My memory is shaky, but it seems to me there’s a heavily algebraic proof that uses only the fact that a real polynomial of odd degree has a real root, and maybe also that all positive reals have real square roots.

Comment: @BenMillwood No offence taken, btw.

Comment: @GitGud: $h(x)=(x-\xi)(x-\bar{\xi})$ exists iff $f(x)$ has a complex root, so we are just hiding the fundamental theorem under the carpet.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio No, $h(x)$ always exists. I don't see what you're getting at.

Comment: @GitGud: By Ruffini's rule, to prove that there is a real quadratic polynomial dividing an even-degree real polynomial is equivalent to proving that the original even-degree polynomial has a complex root.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: See my comments to Georges Elencwajg's answer. Do you agree? I might be wrong or miss the point entirely ...

Comment: @String: I completely agree with you. There is no irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ with degree $3$ or more because complex roots come in conjugate pairs. Maybe it is possible to prove Git Gud's argument without making explicit mention of $\mathbb{C}$ (perhaps using Viete's formulas and some continuity argument), but IMHO this approach just re-phrases some proof of the fundamental theorem, and it is not a *really alternative* way. And the proof with Galois theory requires Galois theory, so we must know that the roots of a polynomial lie in some algebraic extension of the base field!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1) If you know that every irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb R$ has degree $1$ or $2$, you immediately conclude that $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed:

Else there would exist a simple  algebraic extension $\mathbb C\subsetneq  K=\mathbb C(a)$ with $[K/\mathbb C]=\operatorname {deg}_\mathbb C a=d\gt 1$.
Then $K=\mathbb C(a)=\mathbb R(i,a)=\mathbb R(b)$ for some $b\in K$ by the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem)
But then the minimal polynomial $f(X)\in \mathbb R[X]$ of $b$ over $\mathbb R$  would be  irreducible  over $\mathbb R$ and have degree $\operatorname {deg} f(X)=2d\gt 2$, a contradiction to our hypothesis.

2) That said it is possible to prove  that every irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb R$ has degree $1$ or $2$ without using the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra for $\mathbb C$.
The method is due to Lagrange and is described in Samuel's [*Algebraic Theory of Numbers*](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Algebraic_theory_of_numbers.html?id=uQzvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), pages 44-45.
The method consists in inducting on the largest power $r$ of $2$ dividing the degree $d=2^rl$ ($l$ odd) of an irreducible real polynomial,  the result being clear  for $r=0$ i.e. for odd $n$.
The proof (highly non trivial) proceeds by a clever application of Viète's formulas expressing the coefficients of a polynomial as symmetric functions of the roots of that polynomial.

3) Another real methods  proof uses Galois theory and Sylow $2$-groups.
It can be found in [Fine-Rosenberg's](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387946578) Theorem 7.6.1
That elementary and pedagogical book is entirely devoted to all kinds of  proofs of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

Comment: What is that funny $\mathbb C$, you are using? Never heard of it ;)

Comment: @String: $\mathbb C$  is just the field $\mathbb R[T]/(T^2+1)$, the field  obtained by canonically adjoining a root of the irreducible polynomial $T^2+1$ to $\mathbb R$. The fact that this field is algebraically closed is called the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. As the name suggests, it is considered a difficult result and the first part of my answer shows that the question asked is just as difficult as the Fundamental Theorem. Which does not mean that you can't solve the question without mentioning that Fundamental Theorem:  references are given in parts 2) and 3) of my answer.

Comment: OK, I am just questioning the causality here. I believe that the historical development of Galois theory presupposes the construction of some field isomorphic to the complex plane so that any quadratic equation has two definable roots. The second method you mention, however, seem to could have been produced well before accepting the "imaginary solutions" to quadratic equations as definable objects, if I understand you correctly. Thus it would not directly imply the fundamental theorem of algebra before some version of $\mathbb C$ was constructed - possible at a much later date, or never.

Comment: What I am trying to say here is, that just because $prop\ A\iff prop\ B$ does not mean that $prop\ B$ has ever to have been proposed to be able to prove $prop\ A$. Maybe the names for the objects that $prop\ B$ describe have not even been coined yet. Then we cannot be trying to hide $prop\ B$ or its objects under the carpet. They just lay there, and we have not discovered them yet - maybe we never will ...

Comment: That "carpet statement" was aimed at @JackD'Aurizio 's comment to GitGud.

Comment: In fact, it doesnt't answer the question.
Let me explain. Irreducible polynoms over the reals don't need the complex numbers itself. Imagine that you haven't ever heard about it. The second and the third method just trying to proof the fundamental theorem in some way.

Comment: For example, you know that every polynom $P\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ with only positive values can be expressed as $F^2+G^2$ for some $F$ and $G\in\mathbb{R}[x]$.
It is easy corollary from the fact we discuss. But it can be proved without it.

Comment: You proved that $[\mathbb{C}(a):\mathbb{R}]=2d$, but it doesn't mean $[\mathbb{R}(a):\mathbb{R}]=2d$, so you can't conclude that the minimal polynomial oc $a$ over $\mathbb{R}$ has degree $2d$.

Comment: @Xiang Yu  You are right: I have corrected the answer in an edit. Thank you for your vigilance.

Comment: By the way, (3) Fine-Rosenberger's proof using Galois theory and Sylow 2-groups can be found https://jeremykun.com/2012/02/02/the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra-galois-theory/

Comment: Sorry but I didn't follow the step that the degree of minimal polynomial of b is 2d, can you explain that?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. Here's a proof, taken from my article *Another Proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra* (American Mathematical Monthly, vol. 112(**1**), 2005, pp. 76–78).

It is enough to prove that if $\times\colon\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R^n$ is a bilinear map such that $(\Bbb R^n,+,\times)$ is a field, then $n=2$. That's so because if $p(x)\in\Bbb R[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial with degree $n$, then $\Bbb R[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a field extension of $\Bbb R$ whose dimension is $n$ and from it we can induce a field structure on $\Bbb R^n$ for which the addition is the usual one.

So, assume that $n>1$ and that you have defined a product $(x,y)\mapsto x\cdot y$ such that $(\Bbb R^n,+,\cdot)$ is a field. Take any norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\Bbb R^n$ and define a new norm $|\cdot|$ as follows:$$|x|=\sup_{\|y\|\leqslant1}\|x\cdot y\|.$$Then $|1|=1$ and $(\forall x,y\in\Bbb R^n):|x\cdot y|\leqslant|x||y|$. The series$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(x-1)^n}n$$are both absolutely and locally uniformly convergent with respect to this norm, the first one in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the second one in $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid|x-1|<1\}$. Their sums are denoted by $\exp(x)$ and $\log(x)$, respectively. Since the product is commutative, it is easy to prove that$$(\forall x,y\in\Bbb R^n):\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\cdot\exp(y).$$Furthermore, we never have $\exp(x)=0$, because\begin{align}\exp(x)\cdot\exp(-x)&=\exp(x-x)\\&=\exp(0)\\&=1.\end{align}We have thus defined a continuous group homomorphism $\exp:(\mathbb{R}^n,+)\longrightarrow(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$.

It can be proved, just as it is in the case of matrices, that$$\exp\bigl(\log(x)\bigr)=x\quad(x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\ |x-1|<1)\tag1$$and$$\log\bigl(\exp(x)\bigr)=x.\tag2$$for any $x$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $|\exp(x)-1|<1$.

It follows from $(1)$ that, if $V$ is a neighborhood of $0$, then $\exp(V)$ is a neighborhood of $1$. Therefore, since $\exp$ is also a group homomorphism, it is an open mapping. It can be deduced from this fact that $\exp$ is surjective. Indeed, if $G=\exp(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $G$ is an open subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$, and if $x$ belongs to $(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})\setminus G$, then $$G\cdot x\subset\bigl(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\bigr)\setminus G.$$ Accordingly, the complement of $G$ in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ is also an open set. Therefore, since $\Bbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ is connected (this is where $n>1$ is used), the complement of $G$ must be empty. In other words, $\exp(\mathbb{R}^n)=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$.

It is a consequence of $(2)$ that $\ker(\exp)$ is discrete, and it is well known that, unless $\ker(\exp)=\{0\}$, this implies the existence of linearly independent vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$ ($m\geqslant1$) such that $\ker(\exp)=\bigoplus_{k=1}^m\Bbb{Z}v_k$. A second application of the fact that $\exp$ is an open mapping shows that it induces a homeomorphism from $\Bbb{R}^n/\ker(\exp)$ (which is homeomorphic to $(S^1)^m\times\Bbb{R}^{n-m}$) onto $\Bbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$. But if $n>2$, the space $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ would be simply connected, whereas $(S^1)^m\times\Bbb{R}^{n-m}$ is not simply connected when $1\leqslant m\leqslant n$. To avoid a contradiction, it would have to be the case that $\ker(\exp)=\{0\}$. Therefore, $\Bbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ would be homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^n$. However, this is impossible. This follows from the fact that in $\Bbb{R}^n$ every compact set $K$ is a subset of some other compact set whose complement is connected, whereas in $\Bbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ this is not true (consider, for instance, $K=S^{n-1}$, the unit sphere in $\Bbb{R}^n$). Therefore, $n=2$ and the theorem is proved.