# Is $f(x)=x^3-9x^2+6x-12$ irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I want to show that $f(x)=x^3-9x^2+6x-12$ is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field I know that if $f$ has a root in $\mathbb{R}$ then $f$ has a linear factor and hence it is reducible. My way of checking this seems like "cheating" because we don't talk about the notion of continuity in ring theory. One can easily show that $f(0)<0$ and $f(3)>0$, and since polynomials are continuous, the intermediate value theorem guarantees that $f$ has a root in $\mathbb{R}$. How could I show this in another way? Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using continuity to show the required result.

Comment: The only irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ is of degree 1 or 2, since $[\mathbb{C} : \mathbb{R}]=2$ . Also every odd degree polynomial has atleast one real root...

Comment: the real root of the polynomial is $x=8.458372475$!

Comment: Actually $f(3)<0$, but $f(9)>0$. Using continuity is fine.

Comment: If you don't talk about the notion of continuity, you aren't talking about $\mathbb{R}$. A defining feature of $\mathbb{R}$ is its completeness, and without it I think there's no way to show that $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You are essentially in need of the fundamental theorem of algebra, and [there is no way around the real/complex analysis involved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165996/is-there-a-purely-algebraic-proof-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra?noredirect=1&lq=1) since $\mathbb R$ has completeness baked into it.

Answer (score 5):

Irreducible polynomials over the real numbers have degree $1$ or $2$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116965/irreducible-polynomials-over-the-reals). So any real cubic polynomial is reducible.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't talk about the notion of continuity, you aren't talking about $\mathbb{R}$. A defining feature of $\mathbb{R}$ is its completeness, and without it I think there's no way to show that $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose you managed to show $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$, without using completeness of $\mathbb{R}$, then the same argument would work if you replace each with $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$.
The reason is that [the axioms for the real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach) are the same as those for the rational numbers, other than the axiom of completeness. So any argument about $\mathbb{R}$ that doesn't use completeness must work for $\mathbb{Q}$ as well.

Since $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, there's no way to prove $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$ without using its completeness.

Answer (score 1):

[Cardano's method gives nice numbers for this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method). the real root is
$$ 3 + \sqrt[3]{24 + \sqrt{233}} +  \sqrt[3]{24 - \sqrt{233}} \; \; \approx \; \;  8.458372474   $$

Answer (score 0):

The continuity argument is the easiest. However here is another one:
Your polynomial $P$ has three roots in $\mathbb{C}$, if $\lambda$ is a root which is not real, then $\bar{lambda}$ too, because $P(\bar{\lambda}) = \bar{P(\lambda)}$. So $P$ = $(X - \lambda)(X- \bar{\lambda})(X-\mu)$. By identifying the degree 2 coefficient, you have  $-\mu - lambda - \bar{\lambda} \in \mathbb{R}$ and so $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$.